# Where to place a nested union in a struct in C?

Tags: c, struct, unions

I have an anonymous union nested within a struct, as well as other common fields. Is there any reason to place the union in a specific place within the struct (e.g. first or last)?

For example, is this:

```
typedef struct _Message
{
    MessageType type;
    union
    {
        SystemMessageArgs systemArgs;            
        OtherMessageArgs usbArgs;
    };
} Message;
```

better than this:

```
typedef struct _Message
{        
    union
    {
        SystemMessageArgs systemArgs;            
        OtherMessageArgs usbArgs;
    };
    MessageType type;
} Message;
```

in any way?

The context is embedded-C, specifically TI's MSP430

Comment: There is no specific difference between the two. For some very advanced and specific memory layout reasons there could be a difference, but if you don't have any special need they are perfectly equivalent.

Comment: I dont think so, hope your union types have the same length. I prefer the union to be the last element

Comment: You can use `sizeof` to see which struct has less padding bytes.

Comment: @Miguel13366 Why is it important that the union types have the same length?  The compiler will allocate the largest possible space. Or are you referring to a potential waste of memory?

Comment: If you not have the same lengtht, there is a non adressable gap between your structure elements (for your second suggestion with type as last element), depending on which union element is used for the access. This can be desired (see what Magisch or Frankie_C have written), but I trie to avoid this.

Comment: @Miguel13366: The size of a union is always the same.

Comment: Names starting with underscores followed by an uppercase name are reserved for the implementation/standard library. Don't use them!

Comment: @Olaf Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Olaf

`typedef struct Message
{        
    union
    {
        int systemArgs;            
        short int usbArgs;
    };
    int type;
} Message;`


Maybee this explains what I mean.

Comment: @Miguel13366: No, it does not. The `struct` has always the same size and the offset of `type` is constant.

Comment: @Olaf that is what I have said.
But with 'usbArgs'and 'type' is not the complete memory of the struct accessible. And then it makes a difference, if the union is before or after 'type' in the struct

Comment: @Miguel13366: No: "I dont think so, hope your union types have the same length." - How is that relevant for the surounding `struct` or how the members should be ordered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a possible difference in padding, you can find that out by using `sizeof()` on both of them and comparing the results. This may be relevant if you are dealing with heavily constrained memory amounts.

Other than that, they are equivalent.

Comment: That can be true for both placement variants.

Comment: @Olaf Yes, thats why I am suggesting he tests it. I have no crystal ball for how his system will decide to pad that.

Comment: That's why the question is mostly opinionated, thus OT.

Comment: @Olaf I disagree. Which one is better is dependant on his system, and I gave him a way to find out. The one with less padding (if one has less) is better in a specific context, there is no opinion about that.

Comment: Can you outline a scenario where the two-element structures are of different sizes depending on the order of the elements?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Some embedded systems may have very small memory blocks of like 32 bit. Then you get a 16 bit element followed by a 8 bit element. Assume some fixed element unrelated is positioned 14 bits before end of a memory page. Now if the first element is stored first, it skips the rest of that page and takes the next. Thats an educated guess, I could be wrong and it could be that this never happens.

Comment: Bits?  Did you mean bytes?  Even ignoring bits vs bytes, I'm not sure you've outlined a plausible scenario. Indeed, I think the size of a two-element structure will always be the same regardless of the order of definition of the two elements.  Add more elements and things change.  It's a slightly special case.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler What I mean by that is this: Suppose you have 2 elements with differing size: a and b. Now the memory page the system is currently on has x bytes left, where x is big enough to fit a in but not b. In that case, the order would matter, no?

Comment: No; the whole structure has to be stored and aligned as if it was the first element of an array of the structure type.  In the absence of compiler-specific non-standard features, there couldn't be a difference.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Presuming this is embedded hardware, many of which deliver their own compiler package, maybe that edge case could be in fact the case.

Comment: The size of a given layout of the structure must be the same regardless of where it is placed. Any padding will ensure that when the structure is allocated on its correct alignment, the elements within the structure will be properly aligned too.  However, even if you use packing, I can't envisage a scenario where reversing the order of the elements in a two-element structure would change the size.  I don't think further discussion is going to be fruitful. People can see my concern and decide for themselves.